# BehaviourSubject hit multiple times if there is only one value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

I have used behaviourSubject in shared service to get the current value while clicking a button.It is working as expected but some times the api call inside the subscribe block of behavioursubject hits multiple times.

what will be the issue??

Comment: put your code please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], but most likely, you didn't unsubscribe from the subscriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There can be any of the following reasons:**

1. This happens, when you subscribe to BehaviorSubject in a block of code that executes multiple times. Example if you subscribe in ngAfterViewChecked life cycle hook of angular component that executes multiple times.
2. You never unsubscribed but every time app loads the component, subscribe your behaviour subject.
3. Subscriber of BehaviorSubject always executes at least once, because BehaviorSubject requires a default argument when created and emits the passed default argument at least once, if you call .next() method only once on the instance of BehaviorSubject, Subscriber will execute twice. 1st time for default value passed while creating instance of BehaviorSubject, 2nd time for the value you passed by calling .next method on the instance of BehaviorSubject.

Did I answer your question ?

If not, please provide the code snippet, so that we could understand the problem better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. I didn't unsubscribes the Behavior Subject that was the issue